# How to work with forloop and template model?

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, django-models, django-templates

Here I am using simple a card snippet for all the post shown in post_list template. And I have added a template model so when i click on particular post it show me that model with the content of the post on which i clicked.
With the following code, Almost everything is working okay but when i click on any post it show me the content of first post. I want to see content of the post in a model on which i clicked.

```
{% for post in post_list%}
         <div class="cardbox">
          <div class="cardbox-heading">
           <div class="media m-0">
            <div class="d-flex mr-3">
             <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive img-circle" src="{{post.username.avatar.url}}" alt="User"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="media-body">
             <p class="m-0">{{post.username}}</p>
             <small><span>{{post.create_date|timesince}}</span></small>
            </div>
           </div><!--/ media -->
          </div><!--/ cardbox-heading -->
          
          <div class="cardbox-item">
           <a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="{{post.image_data.url}}" alt="MaterialImg">
           </a> 
          </div><!--/ cardbox-item -->      
         </div><!--/ cardbox -->
 Modal Section
     =============================================== -->
     <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
       <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
        
         <div class="row">
         
          <div class="col-md-8 modal-image">
           <img class="img-responsive" src="{{post.image_data.url}}" alt="Image"/>
          </div><!--/ col-md-8 -->
          <div class="col-md-4 modal-meta">
           <div class="modal-meta-top">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
             <span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span>
            </button><!--/ button -->
            <div class="img-poster clearfix">
             <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive img-circle" src="{% static 'assets/img/users/18.jpg'%}" alt="Image"/></a>
             <strong><a href="#">Benjamin</a></strong>
             <span>12 minutes ago</span><br/>
             <a href="#" class="kafe kafe-btn-mint-small"><i class="fa fa-check-square"></i> Following</a>
            </div><!--/ img-poster -->
           </div><!--/ modal-meta-top -->
          </div><!--/ col-md-4 -->
          </div><!--/ row -->
            </div><!--/ modal-body -->
</div><!--/ modal-content -->
      </div><!--/ modal-dialog -->
     </div><!--/ modal -->
 {% endfor %}
```

if more information is required than tell me i will update my question with that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is the #myModal . In html id of elements must be unique, so use something like `id="myModal{{ post.id }}"` and `<a href="#myModal{{ post.id }}" ...`. Or `{{ post.pk }}` or whatever is available